# Suspend closes applications and brings me to login

Tags: 20.04, login, suspend

When I suspend my desktop, I am almost immediately brought to the login page, and when I log back in, my applications have been shut down. Potentially related: powering off brings me to the login page before shutting down.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Look at `sudo journalctl  --since="-15 minutes"` (adjust the "`15`" to cover the beginning of the shutdown). Read `man journalctl sudo`.

Comment: isn’t it the same as https://superuser.com/questions/1617933/debian-suspend-does-logout-instead-of-suspend